# Should Atollic Studio be pausing on interrupts while debugging?

Tags: debugging, interrupt, stm32

I'm using Atollic TrueSTUDIO for ARM 5.0.0 Lite for debugging an STM32F3 application via the SWD debug interface. The application receives data via interrupts from a USART.

When I "step over" a relatively long function, the application doesn't pause, i.e. the program does not reach the line after the call. When I then manually pause the application, I find it to be at the entry of the USART ISR, so I concluded that the execution was paused, even though Atollic's debugger didn't recognize it.

The bigger problem is that the same happens when I simply resume: I can't run my application with the debugger attached, as every byte on the USART pauses it.

Is my analysis of the situation correct? Is this the expected behavior, and is there a way to work around it? Non-Atollic specific answers are also very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I couldn't form a clear picture in my mind of what's really going on, but here's a possibility: you're not clearing the proper flags using the `USART_ClearITPendingBit()` function call from the standard peripheral library, or its equivalent in terms of direct register access. If you don't clear the proper bits, as soon as you return from the ISR, the hardware executes it again, so it looks like you're in an infinite loop inside the ISR.